# Use Oracle's BITAND with a multiple-value parameter

Tags: oracle

Trying to find an elegant way to be able to filter a query, using `BITAND` where the values to be `and`ed are supplied by a multiple-value parameter.

Testing data:

```
WITH

patient as
(
  select 1 patient_id, 'foo' patient_name from dual
  union all
  select 2 patient_id, 'bar' patient_name from dual
  union all
  select 3 patient_id, 'baz' patient_name from dual
  union all
  select 4 patient_id, 'zoo' patient_name from dual

)

,
-- each organ is a power of 2
organ as 
(
  select 2 organ_id, 'Lung' organ_name from dual
  union all
  select 4 organ_id, 'Pancreas' organ_name from dual
  union all
  select 8 organ_id, 'Liver' organ_name from dual
  union all
  select 16 organ_id, 'Kidney' organ_name from dual
)

,
patient_organ as
(
  -- patient with a multi-organ transplant
  select 1 patient_id, 4 organ_id from dual
  union all
  select 1 patient_id, 16 organ_id from dual
  union all

  -- patient with a single-organ transplant
  select 2 patient_id, 4 organ_id from dual
  union all

  -- patient with a multi-organ transplant
  select 3 patient_id, 8 organ_id from dual
  union all
  select 3 patient_id, 16 organ_id from dual
  union all

  -- patient with a single-organ transplant
  select 4 patient_id, 2 organ_id from dual

)
```

This query:

```
select  p.patient_id, p.patient_name
        ,po.bits,po.organs
from    patient p
inner join (

  SELECT  patient_id, sum(organ_id) AS BITS
          ,listagg(organ, '; ') within group (order by organ_id) ORGANS
  FROM    (
    SELECT  patient_id, po.organ_id, o.organ_name || ' [' || o.organ_id || ']' organ
    FROM    patient_organ po
    INNER JOIN organ o ON po.organ_id = o.organ_id
   )
  GROUP BY patient_id

) po on p.patient_id=po.patient_id
```

Generates the desired data set; the multiple organs (e.g. `Pancreas [4]; Kidney [16]`) are displayed:

```
PATIENT_ID, PATIENT_NAME, BITS, ORGANS
1   foo 20  Pancreas [4]; Kidney [16]
2   bar 4   Pancreas [4]
3   baz 24  Liver [8]; Kidney [16]
4   zoo 2   Lung [2]
```

I want to be able to supply a parameter value of `4,8` and get these results:

```
PATIENT_ID, PATIENT_NAME, BITS, ORGANS
1   foo 20  Pancreas [4]; Kidney [16]
2   bar 4   Pancreas [4]
3   baz 24  Liver [8]; Kidney [16]
```

If I have a single value (simulated with `:organ`=4), I can use `BITAND` and get the multi-organ values:

```
select  p.patient_id, p.patient_name
        ,po.bits,po.organs
from    patient p
inner join (

  SELECT  patient_id, sum(organ_id) AS BITS
          ,listagg(organ, '; ') within group (order by organ_id) ORGANS
  FROM    (
    SELECT  patient_id, po.organ_id, o.organ_name || ' [' || o.organ_id || ']' organ
    FROM    patient_organ po
    INNER JOIN organ o ON po.organ_id = o.organ_id
   )
  GROUP BY patient_id

) po on p.patient_id=po.patient_id
WHERE bitand(bits,:organ)=:organ
```

Multi-organs preserved:

```
PATIENT_ID, PATIENT_NAME, BITS, ORGANS
1   foo 20  Pancreas [4]; Kidney [16]
2   bar 4   Pancreas [4]
```

I can use a multiple-value parameter (simulated by `&organs`=4,8):

```
select  p.patient_id, p.patient_name
        ,po.bits,po.organs
from    patient p
inner join (

  SELECT  patient_id, sum(organ_id) AS BITS
          ,listagg(organ, '; ') within group (order by organ_id) ORGANS
  FROM    (
    SELECT  patient_id, po.organ_id, o.organ_name || ' [' || o.organ_id || ']' organ
    FROM    patient_organ po
    INNER JOIN organ o ON po.organ_id = o.organ_id
    WHERE   po.organ_id IN (&organs)
   )
  GROUP BY patient_id

) po on p.patient_id=po.patient_id
```

But this loses the multi-organ results:

```
PATIENT_ID, PATIENT_NAME, BITS, ORGANS
1   foo 4   Pancreas [4]
2   bar 4   Pancreas [4]
3   baz 8   Liver [8]
```

Ideally, I'd be able to use the `BITAND` function with the `IN` statement, but this isn't syntactically valid.

Is there another non-procedural approach?

** edit **

To clarify, I'm referencing this SQL in a reporting tool (Crystal Reports).  The tool allows you to select one or more parameter values: you seen the `organ_name`, but the `organ_id` is supplied.  Moreover, the parameter's values are supplied as an array or a comma-delimited string (hard to say which), not summed to a single value (as suggested in the answer and comments).  This architecture is what makes this difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to query your summarized data for patients that have had at least one of a list of organs transplanted. You should be able to do that simply by changing the predicate in your first attempt from:

```
WHERE bitand(bits,:organ)=:organ
```

to

```
WHERE bitand(bits,:organ) != 0
```

You can then supply a bit mask of the organs you are interested in (e.g. the bit mask for  `Pancreas [4]` and `Kidney [16]` would be `20` while the bit mask for `Pancreas [4]` and `Liver [8]` would be `12`).  This will work since as long as one bit in the mask matches the bitand result will be non zero, if none match the bitand result would be zero.

To use a multiple-value parameter you just need to convert it to a bitmask and replace the :organ bind value with the derived bitmask like this:

```
WHERE bitand(bits,(select sum(distinct organ_id) from organ where organ_id in (&organs))) !=0
```

In this case I'm simulating the multi-value parameter as you did, and converting it to a bit mask in a scalar valued subquery against the organ table.

Comment: @craig -  I concur - Sentinel beat me to it. To further clarify: when you compare two multi-bit codes (such as the `BITS` values for individual patients against a code like 20 to test for Pancreas or Kidney), the condition `bitand(bits, :organ) = :organ` means that the patient has had transplants for ALL the codes in `:organ`. By contrast, the condition `bitand(bits, :organ) > 0` (the way I would prefer to write it) means that the two have non-empty intersection - the patient had AT LEAST ONE of the organ transplants, for the organs represented in the bit code `:organ`.

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence @mathguy I too was initially using `> 0 ` but decided to switch to `!= 0` since the bitand function operates on n-bit two's complement binary integer values.  As such they can take on negative values in addition to positive.  Using `!=` instead allows the sign bit to be used in addition to all the remaining bits.  In Oracle 12c n=128 bits so you can have atmost 128 distinct items identified by a single bit mask.

Comment: I think due to two's complement number `BITAND` works only up to 127 bits. If you have to work with more than 127 bits then use function `UTL_RAW.BIT_AND`.